# XMLHttpRequest...Un problema de velocidades... creo

Tags: php, javascript

el codigo siguiente, funciona a la perfección siempre que sea desde el ordenador donde se aloja el servidor web, sin embargo, desde la red local o desde fuera de ella, no consigo que funcione.
Creo que cuando se ejecuta la funcion firmar(), es tan rápido que solo muestra el último elemento del Combobox4 y pasa de largo sobre "window.location.href = "/firmar.php?valor="+idepi; "

Si meto algun "alert" por medio, parece que al esperar la respuesta del usuario, va funcionando unas veces y otras no,
a ver si me alumbrais alguna idea para solucionarlo... Gracias..

```
   function firmar(){
    var cuantos=document.getElementById("Combobox4");
//Comprueba si se han añadido elementos dentro de Combobox4
    if(cuantos.length==0){
      alert("Debe elegir al menos un elemento de la lista de material...")
      return false;
    }

    var idepi=document.getElementById("Editbox2").value;
    var usuario=document.getElementById("usuario").value;   
    //Recorre el Combobox4 y llama a un php que inserta los datos en una tabla mysql.
     $("#Combobox4 option").each(function(){

            var str=$(this).text();
            var res = str.split("..........| ");
            var uno = res[1];
            var cero = res[0]; 
            var url = "docepi.php";
            var params="cantidad="+cero+"&idEpi="+idepi+"&usuario="+usuario+"&elemento="+uno;  

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", url, true);

    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);

        }

    }
    http.send(params);
        });//fin del bucle 
     //fin de la funcion firmar
    window.location.href = "/firmar.php?valor="+idepi; 
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La ejecución del código JavaScript es asíncrono por naturaleza (de alguna forma, puedes consultar más a detalle en este [vídeo de cómo funciona el event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)).

Mi punto es, cuándo mandas a llamar el método firmar, el va a realizar los pasos seguidos, no va a esperar las respuestas de las peticiones HTTP, es por eso que realiza la redirección sin importar si las peticiones han sido resueltas.

Además en la línea donde indicas los parámetros de la petición http, estas marcándola como asíncrona:

```js
    http.open(method: "POST", url: "docepi.php", async: true /* Aquí la marcas como asíncrona */);
```

Una opción es que hagas la redirección dentro del evento de respuesta de la petición:

```js
    if (http.readyState == 4 ...) {
        // Comprobar aquí que sea el último elemento del combo
        // Si es así, hacer la redirección
        window.location.href = "/firmar.php?valor="+idepi; 
    }
```

Comment: La redirección no puedo hacerla hasta que termine el bucle, de todas formas, con Async:false.. todo perfect.....se me pasó ese "pequeño detalle"...Thanks...

Comment: Genial, si consideras que la respuesta resuelve tu cuestión podrías marcarla como aceptada o autoresponder tu pregunta (marcándola como aceptada) para quiénes consulten esta pregunta a futuro.